# thread.join does not return when called in global var destructor

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl

Using C++11 STL with VS2013 to implementing a asynchronous print class.
Failing to get thread.join() returns with no deadlocking.
I am trying to debug and finally find this issue may caused by global/local class variable declaration. Here is the details and I dont know why it happened?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include "tbb/concurrent_queue.h"
using namespace std;

class logger
{
public:
    ~logger()
    {
        fin();
    }

    void init()
    {
        m_quit = false;
        m_thd = thread(bind(&logger::printer, this));
        //thread printer(bind(&logger::printer, this));
        //m_thd.swap(printer);
    }

    void fin()
    {
        //not needed
        //unique_lock<mutex> locker(m_mtx);
        if (m_thd.joinable())
        {
            m_quit = true;
            write("fin");
            //locker.unlock();

            m_thd.join();
        }
    }

    void write(const char *msg)
    {
        m_queue.push(msg);
        m_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void printer()
    {
        string msgstr;
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(m_mtx);
        while (1)
        {
            if (m_queue.try_pop(msgstr))
                cout << msgstr << endl;
            else if (m_quit)
                break;
            else
                m_cond.wait(locker);
        }
        cout << "printer quit" <<endl;
    }

    bool m_quit;
    mutex m_mtx;
    condition_variable m_cond;
    thread m_thd;
    tbb::concurrent_queue<string> m_queue;
};
```

For more convenience I placed thread.join into class's destructor in order to ensure the m_thread can be quit normally.
I test the whole class and something wrong occured.
**m_thd.join() never return when class logger declared as a global var**
like this:

```
logger lgg;

void main()
{
    lgg.init();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        char s[8];
        sprintf_s(s, 8, "%d", i);
        lgg.write(s);
    }

    //if first call lgg.fin() here, m_thd can be joined normally
    //lgg.fin();

    system("pause");
    //dead&blocked here and I observed that printer() finished successfully 
}
```

**If class logger declared as a local variable, it seems everything works well.**

```
void main()
{
    logger lgg;
    lgg.init();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        char s[8];
        sprintf_s(s, 8, "%d", i);
        lgg.write(s);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

update 2015/02/27

- I tried to delete std::cout in printer(), but program still blocked at same place, seems it is not the std::cout problem?
- Deleting supernumerary lock in `fin()`

Comment: FYI, `thread printer(bind(&logger::printer, this)); m_thd.swap(printer);` is equivalent to `m_thd = thread(&logger::printer, this);`. The problem looks like undefined behavior due to `std::cout` being destroyed before the global logger instance, so that the final `write` call in `fin` causes terrible things to happen. I would write an RAII wrapper to call `init` and `fin`.

Comment: Isn't it a RAII design that I calling fin() in destructor? Could you please do me a example? Thanks very much~

Comment: Maybe you mean a wrapper like this?`RaWrapper(logger *pLgg){pLgg->init();}`  `~RaWrapper(){m_pLgg->fin();}`   @Casey

Comment: @Casey: No, `std::cout` is still alive at that point.

Comment: @Mgetz It is the answer I'm finding, thanks very muck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globals and statics are constructed and destructed [just prior or post to `DllMain` getting called](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/10/17/10565302.aspx) respectively for [`DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx) The problem with this is that it occurs inside the loader lock. Which is the most dangerous place on the planet to be if [dealing with kernel objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/04/4731478.aspx) as it may cause deadlock, or the application to randomly crash. As such you should never use thread primitives as statics on windows **EVER**. Thus dealing with threading in a destructor of a global object is basically doing the exact things we're warned not to do in `DllMain`.

To [quote Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx)

> The building is being demolished. Don't bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards. And don't line up at the exit to the building so everybody can move their in/out magnet to out. All you're doing is making the demolition team wait for you to finish these pointless housecleaning tasks.

[and again](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/04/4731478.aspx):

> If your DllMain function creates a thread and then waits for the thread to do something (e.g., waits for the thread to signal an event that says that it has finished initializing, then you've created a deadlock. The DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH notification handler inside DllMain is waiting for the new thread to run, but the new thread can't run until the DllMain function returns so that it can send a new DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notification.
>
> This deadlock is much more commonly seen in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, where a DLL wants to shut down its worker threads and wait for them to clean up before it unloads itself. You can't wait for a thread inside DLL_PROCESS_DETACH because that thread needs to send out the DLL_THREAD_DETACH notifications before it exits, which it can't do until your DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler returns.

This also occurs even when using an EXE because the visual C++ runtime cheats and registers its constructors and destructors with the C runtime to be run when the runtime is loaded or unloaded, thus ending up with the same issue:

> The answer is that the C runtime library hires a lackey. The hired lackey is the C runtime library DLL (for example, MSVCR80.DLL). The C runtime startup code in the EXE registers all the destructors with the C runtime library DLL, and when the C runtime library DLL gets its DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, it calls all the destructors requested by the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering how you're using `m_mtx`. The normal pattern is that both thread lock it and both threads unlock it. But `fin()` fails to lock it.

Similarly unexpected is `m_cond.wait(m_mtx)`. This would release the mutex, except that it isn't locked in the first place!

Finally, as `m_mtx` isn't locked, I don't see how `m_quit = true` should become visible in `m_thd`.

Comment: very helpful! `m_cond` will norify by `write()` and `m_mtx` unlocked just after that. indeed there's no need to owns m_mtx during `fin()`.I alter my code but still have the problem above

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is that `std::condition_variable::notify_one` is called while the same `std::mutex` that the waiting thread is holding, is held (happens when `logger::write` is called by `logger::fin`).

This causes the notified thread to immediately block again, and hence the printer thread will block possibly indefinitely upon destruction (or until spurious wakeup).

You should never notify while holding the same mutex as the waiting thread(s).

**Quote** from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one):

> *The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock.*

Comment: @tpoy As I explained, there's a chance that `logger::fin` will *never* return as `m_thd.join()` will block indefinitely or until a spurious wakup.

Comment: @tpoy You can solve the problem by e.g. swapping the lines `write("fin");` and `locker.unlock();` in function `logger::fin`.

Comment: but seems its just a pessimization but not cause the problem?I tried to deleting `unique_lock<mutex> locker(m_mtx);` `locker.unlock();` and still blocking when lgg is global and local lgg can destructor normally.